# Yii: disable optimistic locking

Tags: php, yii, yii2, optimistic-locking

I have enabled the optimistic locking feature in my Yii aplication by accident. Now it is causing problems, and I want to disable it. Is there a painless way to do this (i.e. update my models and CRUD without having to create them again)?

Answer (score 0):

How to use OptimisticLockingActiveRecord:

1. Inherit your model from OptimisticLockingActiveRecord class

   ```
   class MyModel extends OptimisticLockingActiveRecord


   {
       ...


   }
   ```
2. Add optimistic locking field to the update form view file:

   ```
   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>


   <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'lock_version'); ?>


   <?php echo $form->error($model, 'lock_version'); ?>
       ...
   ```
3. Handle StaleObjectError in the controller:

   ...

   ```
    if (isset($_POST['MyModel'])) {


   $model->attributes = $_POST['SiteSettingsData'];


   $model->lock_version = $_POST['MyModel']['lock_version'];

       try { 
           $model->save();
       } catch(StaleObjectError $e) {
           $model->addError('lock_version', 
               Yii::t('app', 'Site settings have been updated by another user'));
       }
   ```

   ...